# Is there any better way to launch outlook add-appointment window in bot application?

Tags: outlook, botframework, cortana

I need to launch outlook calendar appointment in bot application. I found the below code in Microsoft documentation for launching outlook email.

```
var message = context.MakeMessage() as IMessageActivity;
message.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
{
  action = new { type = "LaunchUri", uri = "mailto:someone@example.comsubject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20t e%20body"
   } 
 });
   await context.PostAsync(message);
```

And also i tried the  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to add appointment , it also doesn't work for me.

```
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
            Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // creates a new appointment
            oAppointment.Subject = apt.Subject;
            oAppointment.Body = apt.Body;
            oAppointment.Location = apt.Location;
            oAppointment.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(apt.StartTime);
            oAppointment.End = Convert.ToDateTime(apt.EndTime);
```

Is there any better way to launch outlook calendar appointment.

Comment: Are you tied to needing Outlook to open? If not, consider using Microsoft Graph (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0). It includes a number of calendar API calls you can use. There is a Graph bot sample in the Botbuilder-Samples repo you can reference, as well.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Yes , I need to open the outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code must call `oAppointment.Save`.

What exactly are you trying to do? Silently create an appointment (then you code above needs to call `oAppointment.Save`) or display it to the user (then call `oAppointment.Display`)?

If your code is running on a server, create an iCal file and let the user download and open in (local) Outlook - it will be happy to display the appointment.

Comment: I need to open an Outlook appointment window. I tried to display using o.Appointment.Display .It only working in local when i publish it ,the windows is not opening.

Comment: "Publish"? What do you mean by that? Your code must be running on the machine where the appointment is to be displayed, not on your server. If it is running on a server, se the updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Steve mentioned you could use Microsoft Graph.

You might be able to send an ics file as a media attachment (I haven't tried).

Or you can investigate if the protocol handler outlookcal: supports deep linking.

I think this link tells you how it works in Teams
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links